# Disabling multiple input field if a checkbox is checked for dynamic inputs and reenable it if no

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have several dynamic input fields and checkboxes and i would like to disable the input box if the checkbox having a similar id value is checked

This is the php code:

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

 foreach ($checks as $m => $check) {
    $item ="";
    $checkbox ="";
   $textinput ="";
   $displayx="";

if ($check->mandatory_customer == 1) { //mandatory customer checks
 $displayx .="<i style='color:red;'>*</i>";
  $item .=  $check->item.$displayx;
   $checkbox .='<input type="checkbox" class="1" id="'.$m.'"' ;
   $textinput .='<input type="text" class="1" id="'.$m.'"' ;

     } else { //not mandatory customer
    $item .=  $check->item;
   $checkbox .='<input type="checkbox" class="0" id="'.$m.'"' ;
 $textinput .='<input type="text" class="0" id="'.$m.'"' ;

    }

echo "<tr id='" . $m . "'>";
echo "<td>" . $m . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
echo "<td>".$checkbox."</td>";
echo "<td>".$textinput."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
  ?>
     }

</tbody>
```

Now i would like to disable the input boxes having the same id's as the checkboxes if the checkbox is checked. How do i go through this using jquery

Comment: It is not permitted to have the same ID on more than one element.  You should have unique IDs for each element, and use classes or some other means to identify similar elements.

Comment: Am new to html are there other tags i can use other than id and class form inputs

Comment: No need to use other tags. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, it is not permitted to have the same ID on more than one element.  You should update the ID on the lines where you assign `$checkbox` and `$textinput` so that unique ID values are assigned, which will also help you retrieve the submitted values on the other end. Changing them to something like `id="chk_'.$m.'"` and `id="txt_'.$m.'"` would be sufficient.

Also, it looks like you are not closing your input tags.  Add `/>` to the end of the lines where you assign `$checkbox` and `$textinput`, or just `>` if not using HTML 5.

Once you've fixed those issues, the following jquery will work for you:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo:**  https://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/nnphq559/

Comment: Please check this one please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005512/showing-error-in-a-table-row-if-a-checkbox-is-not-checked-or-an-input-field-has

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":checkbox").on("change", function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked"))
                $(":text#"+$(this).attr("id")).prop("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $(":text#" + $(this).attr("id")).removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    });
```

Comment: it fails to disable the input field